# Python pandas excel форматирование ячейки при выполнении условия

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

Используя xlrd и xlsxwriter, сравниваю значения столбцов в разных Excel файлах, при выполнении условия (значение ячейки из файла2 отсутствует в файле1) Мне необходимо изменить цвет шрифта

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_font_color('red')

excel_data_file1 = xlrd.open_workbook('file1.xlsx')
sheet_file1 = excel_data_file1.sheet_by_index(0)

excel_data_file2 = xlrd.open_workbook('file2.xlsx')
sheet_file2 = excel_data_file2.sheet_by_index(0)

col1 = sheet_file1.col(colx=0)
col2 = sheet_file2.col(colx=0)

a=set()
for i in range(len(col1)):
    a.add(sheet_file1.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=0))

for j in range(len(col2)):
    cellVal2 = sheet_file2.cell_value(rowx=j, colx=0)

    if cellVal2 not in a:
        worksheet.write_blank(j, 0, format)
```

при попытки изменить цвет

```
worksheet.write_blank(j, 0, format)
```

в файле2 создается новый лист, может быть есть более короткий пусть с использованием Pandas?!

Comment: Содержит ли `file2.xlsx` другие листы (sheets), которые не должны быть перезаписаны?

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных. Есть ли имена у столбцов в Excel  файлах?